# Making dictionary of dataframes from dictionary of dictionaries in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a nested dictionary:

```
    Night_interval={
    '2010': {
      Timestamp('2010-07-01 00:00:00'): 29,
      Timestamp('2010-07-02 00:00:00'): 28,
      Timestamp('2010-07-03 00:00:00'): 28,
      Timestamp('2010-07-04 00:00:00'): 29,
      Timestamp('2010-07-05 00:00:00'): 28
            },
    '2011': {
      Timestamp('2010-07-01 00:00:00'): 29,
      Timestamp('2010-07-02 00:00:00'): 28,
      Timestamp('2010-07-03 00:00:00'): 28,
      Timestamp('2010-07-04 00:00:00'): 29,
      Timestamp('2010-07-05 00:00:00'): 28
            },
    '2012': {
      Timestamp('2010-07-01 00:00:00'): 29,
      Timestamp('2010-07-02 00:00:00'): 28,
      Timestamp('2010-07-03 00:00:00'): 28,
      Timestamp('2010-07-04 00:00:00'): 29,
      Timestamp('2010-07-05 00:00:00'): 28
            }
  }
```

Using this dictionary, I want to create a dictionary of dataframes associated with each key, i.e., `2010`, `2011` and `2012`. I also want to put the Timestamp as the indices in each of the dataframes. I tried writing following code:

```
Years = ['2010','2011','2012']
for key in Years:
    df_interval[key] = pd.DataFrame(Night_interval[key])
```

However, I am getting this error:
`ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

I am not able to find where I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried passing in an index? Maybe something like this:
`df_interval[key] = pd.DataFrame('year' : Night_interval[key])`

Comment: It worked except that there should be `{}` around the argument given to `pd.DataFrame()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need dict use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with column name:

```
df_interval = {}
Years = ['2010','2011','2012']
for key in Years:
    df_interval[key] = pd.DataFrame({key:Night_interval[key]})

print (df_interval['2012'])
            2012
2010-07-01    29
2010-07-02    28
2010-07-03    28
2010-07-04    29
2010-07-05    28
```

---

```
df_interval = {}
Years = ['2010','2011','2012']
for key in Years:
    df_interval[key] = pd.DataFrame({'a':Night_interval[key]})

print (df_interval['2012'])
             a
2010-07-01  29
2010-07-02  28
2010-07-03  28
2010-07-04  29
2010-07-05  28
```

Or if only one column is possible create `dict` of `Series`:

```
df_interval = {}
Years = ['2010','2011','2012']
for key in Years:
    df_interval[key] = pd.Series(Night_interval[key], name=key)

print (df_interval['2012'])
2010-07-01    29
2010-07-02    28
2010-07-03    28
2010-07-04    29
2010-07-05    28
Name: 2012, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Could you please tell me regarding the error I was getting?

Comment: Hmmm, hard question for me. I think is necessary column name as `key` of dict or use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Night_interval[key], orient='index')` with default `0` column.